# IBMWebsphere gives SRVE0190E: File not found ERROR

Tags: docker, websphere

I am using docker to deploy and run my application. Everything is fine during deployment and running my application.I am using dockerDeploy and restartWas commends in order to deploy and run my application.

After I run my application , my login and password comes to my screen. Everything is fine at that step as well but after I write my login and password, I come across with the error below. I did not change anything in the code but after I restart docker I come across with the following error.
I restarted docker and also computer several times but I still come across with that. I would be glad if you can help me.

Regards

Error Page Exception

SRVE0260E: The server cannot use the error page specified for your application to handle the Original Exception printed below.

```
Original Exception:

Error Message: SRVE0190E: File not found: {0}
Error Code: 404
Target Servlet: 
Error Stack: 
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: SRVE0190E: File not     found: {0}
```

Comment: any updates here?